# How to create a new table from Query data and change rows to column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI. I have searched a solution, but I can't find the one match my issue.

I use direct query to SQL Server to generate data table in Power BI. My query result as below:

[image: Query Result in Power BI]

And I want to create a new table and transform the data to be as below:

[image: Expecting new Table look like]

Really appreciate any help or idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [pivot](https://radacad.com/pivot-and-unpivot-with-power-bi) the `Factory` column to get the desired result.

In Power BI Desktop designer, click `Transform data` button from the `Home` ribbon tab to open `Power Query Editor`. First, delete the `Comment` column (or don't select it at first place) by right clicking on it's title and select `Remove`. You don't need it. Then select `Factory` column and click `Pivot Column` button from `Transform` tab:

[image]

and select `Volume` for values column:

[image]

This will pivot the column, i.e. make a separate column for each of the values in it, and give you the desired result:

[image]

In addition (you said you are using a DQ to get the data), you can also do the same transformation in the database query too.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrey. I follow your instruction and the table result exactly what I want. And thanks for the idea, I think I should do it in the SQL Query to transform the data. Never thought it before.